# Show Conditional calculation output of Column 1 & 2 in Column 3 in SharePoint 2013 List

Tags: list, sharepoint-server, calculated-column-formula

I`m working on how to get the output of the filtered total value in Column1 and Column 2 and show it in Column 3.
Example for better understanding -

```
**Column 1          Column 2    Column 3 (calculation)**
Complete            period 1    
   1
Not Complete        period 2
Complete            period 3
   1
Complete            period 3
   1
Not complete        period 1
```

Column 3 to pull the total count of Column 1 with value set to Complete along with column 2 with value set to either Period 1 or Period 3.

I guess this can be achieved using Calculated column formula in Column 3.
Please assist.

Comment: Can you copy/paste your columns one more time and enter the values you would like to see in column3, your description of column3 leaves for interpretation

Comment: @danny thanks for inquiring. If column 1 shows complete along with column 2 as period 1 or 3, then vased on the 2 conditins column 3 value to be 1 for that particular row.

Comment: Show us the column.. I am a programmer and able to interpret your text in at least 5 ways (3 of which stupid ofcourse) IE. My first thought was: 1 , 1 , 2 ,2, 1 in column 3

Comment: Whether you want to iterate over all items or not, you can not reference complex fields like Lookups in a CC. You could get the values with code: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/128479/lookup-column-in-calculated-column-formula

Comment: @DannyEngelmanMPW please find screenshot for better understanding. kindly assist, i`ve researched a lot but cant find any rule that would allow conditional formatting to work using calculated columns formula. url: http://imgur.com/4Owv8kt

Comment: See the link I posted, that OR CSR is the only way to get at those complex values

Comment: Thanks for the update. As I'm not good in javascript or csr, any tool that can help to get the job easier?

Comment: @DannyEngelmanMPW just found iCISAR (chrome extension) , looking more to learn the dev part of SPS world.