# formula validation amount field

Tags: sharepoint-online, validation

I have two fields...

Price is an  Amount  field
Approval is a Person or Group field

so if the Ammount field is > $1000, Approval field is required so what is the proper column formula to validate the Approval field?

For example:

If Amount field >1000, Approval Field cannot be null...

UPDATE:

I just found out the Approval Field doesn't have formula field! Now what?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using JQuery:

```
if($('#amountfieldid').val() > 1000){
   if($('#approvalfield').val() == ''){
       alert('Approval field is required!');
       return false;
   } 
}
```

You can use `PreSaveAction()` function to write your custom code before submitting the form.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use lookup fields in `Column and List validation` or `Calculated field` , You will have to use

- The object model to create a validation.
- Or change Lookup field to Choice Field
- Or Javascript Validation as something like this

> ```
> <script type="text/javascript">
>     function PreSaveAction() {
>         var amount= document.getElementById("Lookup Field ID");
>         if (amount.val() > 1000) {
>             alert("");
>             return false;
>         }
>         return true;
>     }
> </script>
> ```

Check a similar thread that may help you [lookup column in calculated column formula](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/128479/lookup-column-in-calculated-column-formula)

Comment: The lookup field is tied to our active directory groups is I can't use a choice field. What about using Jquery validation?

Comment: Please check my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with workflow.

- Create a workflow for this.
- set this will be fired when an item will be created.
- check the condition
- if amount value > 1000 them prompt the user to input Approval field